# GameCenter circle user icon always in upper right corner, how to hide or place somewhere else on screen?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, game-center

I have a super simple app where I am trying to test GameCenter, most of the code is below:

```
import SwiftUI
import GameKit
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var gameCenterUtility = GameCenterUtility()
    let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.local
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: TestView()) {
                Text("Play Game")                                                
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        .onAppear {
            gameCenterUtility.authenticateUser()
        }
    }
}

class GameCenterUtility {
    func authenticateUser() {
        let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.local

        localPlayer.authenticateHandler = { vc, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
                return
            }
            GKAccessPoint.shared.isActive = localPlayer.isAuthenticated
        }
    }
}
```

The challenge I am having is that as you can see below, the circle icon of the user's profile (Giant B) is always displaying in the top-right corner of the screen, hiding anything that's behind it.
[image: Screen shot of sample app]

Is there a way to hide that image circle or move it elsewhere in the app? Nothing in my code tells it to appear in the top right corner of the screen.

Here's the code of the TestView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World or not!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you can set the location of the access point like this

```
GKAccessPoint.shared.location = .topLeading
```

and show/hide it using the `isActive` boolean flag you're already using

```
GKAccessPoint.shared.isActive = false
```

Comment: OMG how did you figure that out?

Comment: from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gkaccesspoint) ;)